# Creating a large nodejs cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, caching

I want to create a large in-memory cache for my REST API. How can I make it so that when the cache gets too large, older objects are purged?

I am using nodejs for this project.

**Edit**: I made a cache class for the time being, is this a scalable and fully optimized approach?

The approach taken here is that there exists in the object a pointer value (`_index`) where cache resources will be put. After that the pointer is incremented. Once the pointer reaches the `limit` value it is set back to zero and the process continues, except this time values at the pointer are being overridden.

```
class Cache {
  constructor(limit = 2048) {

    if (typeof limit !== 'number' || limit <= 0) { limit = Infinity; }

    this.limit = limit;
    this.purge();
  }
  purge() {

    this._index = 0;
    this._values = [];
    this._keys = [];
  }
  put(key, value) {

    if ((let existingIndex = this._indexOf(key)) !== undefined) {
      this._keys[existingIndex] = key;
      this._values[existingIndex] = value;
    } else {
      this._keys[this._index] = key;
      this._values[this._index] = value;
      this._nextIndex();
    }
  }
  get(key) {

    let index = this._indexOf(key);
    if (index === undefined) { return; }
    return this._values[index];
  }
  delete(key) {

    let index = this._indexOf(key);
    if (index === undefined) { return false; }
    this._keys[index] = null;
    this._values[index] = null;
    return true;
  }
  has(key) {

    return this._indexOf(key) !== undefined;
  }
  _indexOf(key) {

    let i = this.limit;
    while (i--) {
      if (this._keys[i] === key) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }
  _nextIndex() {

    this._index += 1;
    if (this._index > this.limit) { this._index = 0; }
  }
}

export default Cache;
```

Comment: I think this link might be helpful : http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-simple-in-memory-cache-in-java-lightweight-cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for what's called a Least Recently Used (LRU) Cache. It will get rid of the oldest accessed data once the size of the cache reaches a specified threshold. This one is pretty popular: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lru-cache